# pass integer array from one class to another

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am having two classes. I am trying to plot a graph from database values
but I am not able to send value from one class to another, where array is being used. please go through my code and help me out.

Following is the class where values of array are present(Right now I am using static values)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.IDemoChart;
import org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart.TemperatureChart;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class ChartDemo extends ListActivity {
    double a = 10;
    double pass[] = { 7, 0, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 19, 11, 4 };
    Intent intent;
    private IDemoChart[] mCharts = new IDemoChart[] { new TemperatureChart() };

    private String[] mMenuText;

    private String[] mMenuSummary;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int length = mCharts.length;
        mMenuText = new String[length];
        mMenuSummary = new String[length];

        TemperatureChart obj=new TemperatureChart();
        obj.getArray(pass);
        for(int i=0;i<pass.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i("sanket",pass[i]+"");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            mMenuText[i] = mCharts[i].getName();
            mMenuSummary[i] = mCharts[i].getDesc();
        }
        setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, getListValues(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {
                        IDemoChart.NAME, IDemoChart.DESC }, new int[] {
                        android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }));
    }

    private List<Map<String, String>> getListValues() {
        List<Map<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        int length = mMenuText.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Map<String, String> v = new HashMap<String, String>();
            v.put(IDemoChart.NAME, mMenuText[i]);
            v.put(IDemoChart.DESC, mMenuSummary[i]);
            values.add(v);
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        // intent = new Intent(this, TemperatureChart.class);

        // if (position <= mCharts.length + 1) {

        intent = mCharts[position].execute(this);

        // intent.putExtra("sam", a);
        // Log.i("sanket",a+"");

        // }

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now this is the second class where I want those array values
The problem is this class is being initialized before filling those items in array so my array in this class is empty

```
package org.achartengine.chartdemo.demo.chart;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type;
import org.achartengine.model.RangeCategorySeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.SimpleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Temperature demo range chart.
 */
public class TemperatureChart implements IDemoChart {
    // static double b;

    double[] maxValues;

    public void getArray(double array1[]) {

        array1 = new double[12];
        this.maxValues = array1;

        for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i("sanket",maxValues[i]+"");
        }
    }


    /**
     * Returns the chart name.
     * 
     * @return the chart name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return "MarkS range chart";
    }

    /**
     * Returns the chart description.
     * 
     * @return the chart description
     */
    public String getDesc() {
        return "The monthly Marks (vertical range chart)";
    }

    /**
     * Executes the chart demo.
     * 
     * @param context
     *            the context
     * @return the built intent
     */
    public Intent execute(Context context) {





        // b = getIntent().getIntExtra("sam", 0);
        // Log.i("sanket",b+"");
        double[] minValues = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        // double[] maxValues = new double[] { 7, 0, 4, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 19,
        // 11,
        // 4 };

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        RangeCategorySeries series = new RangeCategorySeries("Marks");
        int length = minValues.length;
        for (int k = 0; k < length; k++) {
            series.add(minValues[k], maxValues[k]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.CYAN };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly Marks range", "Month",
                "Marks Obtained", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 20, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
        renderer.setXLabels(0);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Jan");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Mar");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "May");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "Jul");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "Oct");
        renderer.addXTextLabel(12, "Dec");
        renderer.addYTextLabel(5, "OK");
        renderer.addYTextLabel(10, "GOOD");
        renderer.addYTextLabel(20, "Nice");
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 70, 10, 0 });
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);
        r.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        r.setChartValuesTextSize(12);
        r.setChartValuesSpacing(3);
        r.setGradientEnabled(true);
        r.setGradientStart(-20, Color.BLUE);
        r.setGradientStop(20, Color.GREEN);
        return ChartFactory.getRangeBarChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer,
                Type.DEFAULT, "Marks Range");
    }

    protected void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
            String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
            double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
            int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
    }

    protected XYMultipleSeriesRenderer buildBarRenderer(int[] colors) {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            r.setColor(colors[i]);
            renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use static variable to pass data between class..

Comment: Your method is fine in this case. Problem will occur in this method only if you want to share this between two *activities*. But for this case I guess this method is fine.

Comment: @InnocentKiller can you please illustrate where can I make changes

Comment: @Gautham Code is fine its working but I am getting all the values as 0

Comment: Okay, can you tell me what exactly you want to pass???

Comment: @InnocentKiller Check the class ChartDemo in that I am using Array Pass
 I want to use that array in next class TemperatureChart
where I want to receive those values in MAXVALUES array

Comment: @SanketNaik: Create [Getter/Setter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html‎) methods for each array you want to access in the _other_ class. This is the secure practice and not pre-loading memory with the use of `static`.

Comment: Okay, so basically create new class and declare your array variable as a static in that class and then access this variable with class name.array variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what you are doing here:

```
public void getArray(double array1[]) {

    array1 = new double[12];
    this.maxValues = array1;

    for(int i=0;i<array1.length;i++)
    {
        Log.i("sanket",maxValues[i]+"");
    }
}
```

You are overwriting input param array1 with new double[12] and therefore this.maxValues.

Comment: `this.maxValues = array1;` should precede `array1 = new double[12];` to prevent unintentional data loss.

Comment: ye
now I am getting the value in log but still graph is not being displayed
thanks 
can you help me for graph as well

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by using static variables and methods. Make the variable you want to share as static. Also write the static methods in the same class to get it. and access that method from another class.You can look at example here:- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/326941/passing-data-between-classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a public class:
public class Values{

public static int[] val = null;

}


//Set array in one class:
Values.val = int[] arr1;//arr1 containing your values


//Get array in another class:
int[] arr2 = Values.val;
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you convert your array into int arraylist and then pass it between activities and then you convert it back to array in the other activty.